# how to install npm for laravel on windows 10 and solve this problem?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I got below error while I try to run npm install.

type:

`npm install`

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 17160 packages in 10.766s
found 2 moderate severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: That's just a warning. Ignore it. :-) fsevents is used only for mac os, so you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error, it is just a warning. The warning indicates you are using Windows OS where the package has been designed for MacOS.

```
Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"}(current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

You can skip this warning and go forward. It will not effect in any ways in your development.